# iOS autolayout implement programmatically with VFL

Tags: ios

I have designed my view in storyboard using auto layout, but I have some problem implementing this programmatically with VFL.
This view looks like this in portrait
[image]

There are three subviews layout vertically in some order, and in some method, we can change their order(i.e. [1,2,3] to [2,3,1]). view1,view2,view3 all has a fixed width=100 and height=100, view2's center equals its superview's center. 
When change to landscape mode, the three subviews layout horizontally in the same order as they were in portrait, like this:
[image]

Hope someone could help me to implement this, thanks for any help! And here you can download my sample project in case that I didn't describe my issue clearly!
https://github.com/SomnusLee1988/SamplePorject

Comment: Have you tried UIStackView?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: afaik you can't setup an equal center constraint (which is one of the constraints you need) with vfl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you can't setup the constraints you need all just with VFL this could be a solution:

```
var view1: UIView!
var view2: UIView!
var view3: UIView!

var variableConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

let metrics = ["width": 100, "height": 100]
var views: [String: AnyObject]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view1 = UIView()
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(view1)

    view2 = UIView()
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(view2)

    view3 = UIView()
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(view3)

    views = ["v1": view1, "v2": view2, "v3": view3]

    setupFixedConstraints()
    setupVariableConstraintsForSize(nil)
}

private func setupFixedConstraints() {
    // width and height
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[v2(width)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v2(height)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

    // center x and center y
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view2, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
}

private func setupVariableConstraintsForSize(size: CGSize?) {
    // remove existing constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(variableConstraints)
    variableConstraints.removeAll()

    let size = size ?? view.frame.size

    if size.width > size.height {
        // landscape
        variableConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[v1(==v2)][v2][v3(==v2)]", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: metrics, views: views)
    } else {
        // portrait
        variableConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v1(==v2)][v2][v3(==v2)]", options: [.AlignAllLeading, .AlignAllTrailing], metrics: metrics, views: views)
    }

    // activate constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(variableConstraints)
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    setupVariableConstraintsForSize(size)
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Slotla, I have one more question. Why can't I setup align center to superview's center constraints with VFL?

Comment: from the documentation: _The notation emphasizes good visualization over completeness. Therefore some constraints (for example, aspect ratios) cannot be created using the visual format language._ same goes for center constraints. i guess you have to ask the guys at apple :)